# How can I restrict Windows device download/upload rate

Tags: windows-7, networking

Is there a way I can restrict the max upload and download rate on Windows 7 to reflect 100kb/s up/down?

Comment: Can you provide a couple more details? Are you looking to do this for Quality of Service on your network? Are you testing software under less than ideal network conditions? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look into Group Policy Editor:

http://www.bukisa.com/articles/459964_how-to-increase-internet-speed-in-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

If you need to limit network speeds for testing purposes, I use a simple network simulator from "Akmalabs" called "Network Simulator". http://www.akmalabs.com/downloads_netsim.php . It's not the easiest to use, but is a free and simple way to simulate packet loss and slow networks.

If it's for Quality of Service (e.g. you don't want one computer to hog all the bandwidth), that's probably better handled by your router. More details about Windows QOS here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd919203(WS.10).aspx